# I am facing below error while running the sql query

Tags: oracle

```
      select a.version,b.section_id,a.component_id,
       a.comp_text, 
       case 
         when a.version=b.comp_version and a.component_id=b.component_id 
          then 'Yes' 
          else 'No' 
      END CurrentVersion 
     from
     (
      select version, component_id,comp_text 
      from cms_components 
      where component_id =1222 and status = 'QC Approved'
      union all
      select version, component_id,comp_text 
      from CMS_COMPONENT_HISTORY where component_id =1222 and status = 'QC Approved'
     ) a,
     DOC_SEC_COMPONENT_DETAILS b 
     where a.component_id = b.component_id 
     and b.section_id =9255 and b.DOC_ID =1747 
    order by a.version desc;
```

output:

```
6.0 9255    1222    <p>main</p><p>Test1</p><p>Test level3</p><p>Test level4</p><p>Test level5</p><p>Test level6</p> No
5.0 9255    1222    <p>main</p><p>Test1</p><p>Test level3</p><p>Test level4</p><p>Test level5</p>   No
4.0 9255    1222    <p>main</p><p>Test1</p><p>Test level3</p><p>Test level4</p> No
3.0 9255    1222    <p>main</p><p>Test1</p><p>Test level3</p>   No
2.0 9255    1222    <p>main</p><p>Test1</p> No
1.0 9255    1222    <p>main</p> Yes
```

Now my requirement is get only max version details :

```
select a.version,b.section_id,a.component_id,a.comp_text, case when a.version=b.comp_version and a.component_id=b.component_id 
then 'Yes' else 'No' END CurrentVersion 
from(
   select version, component_id,comp_text 
   from cms_components 
   where component_id =1222 and status = 'QC Approved'
 union all 
   select version, component_id, comp_text 
   from CMS_COMPONENT_HISTORY 
   where component_id =1222 and status = 'QC Approved') a, DOC_SEC_COMPONENT_DETAILS b 
where a.component_id = b.component_id and b.section_id = 9255 and b.DOC_ID =1747 
and a.version=  max(version)
order by a.version desc;
```

am trying this getting below error

> ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
> 00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
> *Cause:
> *Action: Error at Line: 6 Column: 17
>
> ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
> 00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
> *Cause:
> *Action: Error at Line: 6 Column: 17

Answer (score 2):

Right; `max` can't be used that way:

```
AND a.version = MAX (version)
```

Try

```
AND a.version = (SELECT MAX (version) FROM a)
```

instead.

Comment: This will not work as-is because `a` is a sub-query and is not materialised. If you did want to use it then you need to use a sub-query factoring clause `WITH a AS ( <inner query> ) SELECT ... FROM a INNER JOIN b ON ... WHERE ... AND a.version = (SELECT MAX(version) FROM a)` so that you can reference `a` twice.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` to get the maximum(s):

```sql
select a.version,
       b.section_id,
       a.component_id,
       a.comp_text,
       case
       when a.version=b.comp_version and a.component_id=b.component_id 
       then 'Yes'
       else 'No'
       END AS CurrentVersion 
from   (
         select version,
                component_id,
                comp_text 
         from   cms_components 
         where  component_id =1222
         and    status = 'QC Approved'
       union all 
         select version,
                component_id,
                comp_text 
         from   CMS_COMPONENT_HISTORY 
         where  component_id = 1222
         and    status = 'QC Approved'
       ) a
       INNER JOIN DOC_SEC_COMPONENT_DETAILS b 
       ON a.component_id = b.component_id
WHERE  b.section_id = 9255
and    b.DOC_ID =1747 
order by a.version desc
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

In earlier versions, you can use the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
select version,
       section_id,
       component_id,
       comp_text,
       CurrentVersion 
FROM   (
  select a.version,
         b.section_id,
         a.component_id,
         a.comp_text,
         case
         when a.version=b.comp_version and a.component_id=b.component_id 
         then 'Yes'
         else 'No'
         END AS CurrentVersion,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY version DESC) AS rnk
  from   (
           select version,
                  component_id,
                  comp_text 
           from   cms_components 
           where  component_id =1222
           and    status = 'QC Approved'
         union all 
           select version,
                  component_id,
                  comp_text 
           from   CMS_COMPONENT_HISTORY 
           where  component_id = 1222
           and    status = 'QC Approved'
         ) a
         INNER JOIN DOC_SEC_COMPONENT_DETAILS b 
         ON a.component_id = b.component_id
  WHERE  b.section_id = 9255
  and    b.DOC_ID =1747
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

or, if you are only expecting a single row, you can use `ROWNUM`:

```sql
select * 
FROM   (
  select a.version,
         b.section_id,
         a.component_id,
         a.comp_text,
         case
         when a.version=b.comp_version and a.component_id=b.component_id 
         then 'Yes'
         else 'No'
         END AS CurrentVersion
  from   (
           select version,
                  component_id,
                  comp_text 
           from   cms_components 
           where  component_id =1222
           and    status = 'QC Approved'
         union all 
           select version,
                  component_id,
                  comp_text 
           from   CMS_COMPONENT_HISTORY 
           where  component_id = 1222
           and    status = 'QC Approved'
         ) a
         INNER JOIN DOC_SEC_COMPONENT_DETAILS b 
         ON a.component_id = b.component_id
  WHERE  b.section_id = 9255
  and    b.DOC_ID =1747
  ORDER BY a.version DESC
)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```